ERROR: No HIP GPUs are available and Rocminfo Unable to open /dev/kfd, While trying to install Fooocus on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
I want to run Fooocus on my machine, I have Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS installed, and my graphic card is a AMD Radeon R9.
I followed some instructions on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6ai6rsDps4&t=209s , everything went well, I installed ROCm and Anaconda. Just on the last step when I wanted to run python entry_with_update.py I got the ERROR:
RuntimeError: No HIP GPUs are available

Searching some forums for solutions I came across another issue, this time trying to check the rocminfo. It gave me an Error saying:
ROCk module is loaded
Unable to open /dev/kfd read-write: No such file or directory
veenife is member of video group

